# Leaflet Map plugin shortcode not working inside ajax call function: Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, leaflet

I am using the wordpress plugin Leaflet Map: https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/ in my site.
The maps are loading fine in all other pages however, there is a particular scenario where I am calling the leaflet short code on ajax call request and the maps are going blank here.

> This is my ajax function:

```
  function show_search_listing() {
        var pageurl = jQuery("#pageUrl").text();
        var datastring = jQuery("#seractListingFrm").serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: pageurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery("customClass.et_pb_row_1").html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("An error has occurred");
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

and I am calling this ajax function from a form as below,

```
  <div class="adv-search">
    <span id="pageUrl" style="display:none">' . site_url() . '/wp-content/themes/site/ajax-listing-search.php</span>
    <form action="#" id="seractListingFrm" name="seractListingFrm" method="POST">
        <div id="search_div">
            <input name="search_text" placeholder="State, City, Zip" id="search_text" type="text" class="seacrhinp">
            <input type="button" name="serchBtn" class="serchBtn" onclick="show_search_listing()">
        </div>
        ' . $searchHeaders . '
    </form>
</div>
```

I am calling the leaflet shortcode in my ajax-listing-search.php file something like,

```
$output_2 .= '<div class="rowcol">
               <div class="ft-image">
            ' . do_shortcode("[leaflet-map height=250 width=250 lat=44.67 lng=-63.61 zoom=5]") . '
     </div>
</div>';

return $output_2;
```

However, the above is returning a blank map. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had have a simular problem. I have done following things:

1. I used echo for the output

> echo $output_2;

2. I allowed the Browser to call to https://unpkg.com to where leaflet styles and scripts are hostet dynamically. (Tools like NoScript can blocked the request.) A other solution is to host leaflet locally.